# Stratified Sampling in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to implement stratified sampling in pig using the code below:

```
REGISTER datafu-1.2.0.jar
DEFINE SRS datafu.pig.sampling.SimpleRandomSample('0.01');
pop = LOAD 'pop';
grouped = GROUP pop BY metroid;
strsampled = FOREACH grouped GENERATE FLATTEN(SRS(pop));
strsampled2 = FOREACH (GROUP strsampled all) GENERATE FLATTEN(strsampled);
STORE strsampled2 INTO 'strsample';
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Call From pdnhwhdplinc04.xxxxx.local/0.0.0.0 to pnnhwhdplinc01.xxxxx.local:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Can anyone please provide any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on single node pseudo or distributed? 

Also where are you loading 'pop' from?

Comment: @BasicHorizon. Distributed node. I am sure there is nothing wrong with load 'pop' as I can draw a simple random sample using SAMPLE pop 0.01. The part I am not sure about is datafu-1.2.0.jar that I uploaded and registered with Pig using Hue. I am wondering if I am missing something else.

Comment: When you used SAMPLE pop 0.01 did you also write to 'strsample' as you currently have it?  That is, have you completely isolated the UDF as the problem by removing it?